# Why do I have a syntax error in this bash code?

Tags: bash, git-bash

```
a=0
b=0
numterms=0
echo -e -n "\nEnter a number for variable a: "
read a
echo ""
echo -e -n "\nEnter a number for variable b: "
read b
echo ""
echo -e -n "\nEnter a number for how many terms printed: "
read numterms
echo ""
n=1
numtermss=$(($numterms+1))
while [ $n -lt $numtermss ]
do
        sum=$(($a * $n + $b))
        n=$(($n + 1))
        echo $sum
        if [ $numterms -lt 0 ]
        then
                echo -e -n "Number needs to be postive."
                echo ""
        else
                echo -e -n "\nEnter another number for variable a: "
                read aa
                echo ""
                echo -e -n "n\Enther another number for variable b: "
                read bb
                echo ""
                echo -e -n "n\Enter another number for amount of terms: "
                read terms
                echo ""
                        aa=0
                        bb=0
                        terms=0
                        for i in "$@"
                        do
                        number=(head -1 "$i")
                        bb=$((bb+1))
                        aa=$((aa + number))
                        termss=$(($terms+1))
                        echo " The sum is $aa"
fi
done
```

I'm trying to have the bash code create a linear sequence where the user inputs the variables a, b, and how many terms should be output.
U=a(n)+b
and then chooses other variables for the same linear sequence and output the sum of the count.

Comment: Use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net). Also, you can try removing (/commenting out) sections of code to isolate where a problem is coming from.

Comment: You appear to be missing "done" for the inner loop. `number=(head` is missing a `$`.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a shebang in the beginning, a semicolon in the for loop at the end, and a done to and the for loop. I also added a proper exit command.

```
#!/bin/bash

a=0
b=0
numterms=0
echo -e -n "\nEnter a number for variable a: "
read a
echo ""
echo -e -n "\nEnter a number for variable b: "
read b
echo ""
echo -e -n "\nEnter a number for how many terms printed: "
read numterms
echo ""
n=1
numtermss=$(($numterms+1))
while [ $n -lt $numtermss ]
do
        sum=$(($a * $n + $b))
        n=$(($n + 1))
        echo $sum
        if [ $numterms -lt 0 ]
        then
                echo -e -n "Number needs to be postive."
                echo ""
        else
                echo -e -n "\nEnter another number for variable a: "
                read aa
                echo ""
                echo -e -n "n\Enther another number for variable b: "
                read bb
                echo ""
                echo -e -n "n\Enter another number for amount of terms: "
                read terms
                echo ""
                        aa=0
                        bb=0
                        terms=0
                        for i in "$@";
                        do
                        number=(head -1 "$i")
                        bb=$((bb+1))
                        aa=$((aa + number))
                        termss=$(($terms+1))
                        echo " The sum is $aa"
                done
fi
done
exit 0
```